# Putting javascript charts inside an extjs window

Tags: extjs, jqplot, flot

How would I put an external javascript chart, like one from flot or jqplot, inside an extjs window? I know that I could use the charts that extjs provides, but i want to put a flot or jqplot chart inside the window instead.

Comment: You should be able to get a reference via Ext to a dom element that could host your flot chart.  I don't see why this wouldn't work.  There's no reason you can't include both Ext and jquery in your app.  What specifically have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I just started using ext so I'm not that used to it yet, originally I just tried using the html function in the ext.window for the flot code, but that did not work.

Comment: Maybe create a panel and provide it with a config option of something like `html: "<div id='flotdiv'></div>"`.  Then in some `afterrender` listener for that panel, you could execute the flot chart creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do as Chris said (why didn't you post it as an answer, dude?).

Here's a complete example:

[Live on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/Eg3WS/) (be sure to check the "External Resource" tab; Flot code is from their basic example).

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.widget('window', {
        autoShow: true
        ,shadow: false
        ,title: "Flot in ExtJS"
        ,resizable: true
        ,margin: 10
        ,width: 600
        ,height: 350

        ,html: '<div class="demo-container">'
            + '<div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>'
            + '</div>'

        ,listeners: {
            resize: function(panel) {
                panel.body.down('.demo-container').setSize(panel.body.getSize());
            }
            ,afterrender: function(panel) {
                var el = this.body;
                el.down('.demo-container').setSize(el.getSize());

                var d1 = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
                    d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
                }
                var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];
                var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

                $.plot("#placeholder", [ d1, d2, d3 ]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would follow similar syntax for inputting a jqplot correct? I attempted to do this but I cannot get anything to output and I made sure I had all the correct resources. Here is the jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eKr9m/1/)

Comment: I've taken a look at your fiddle. You've got two problems. First Ext's CSS is missing. Second, jQuery must be loaded before jqplot (see the error: "jQuery is undefined"). I've just changed that in your fiddle (updated version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/eKr9m/2/)) and it works. Unfortunately jqplot doesn't resize automatically as flot does, so you'll have to dig for the right option if you need that.

Comment: Looks like I should have checked my resources a second time, and I found the code for resize on the jqplot webpage. Thanks for your help!