# Extjs with Devexpress ChartJS

Tags: jquery, extjs, devexpress, chart.js

I would like to embed dxChart from Devexpress into a extjs panel...

Here are my basic attempt:

```
           var chart = $('#chartContainer').dxChart({
                                 size:{height:200,height:200},
                                 commonSeriesSettings: {
                                     label: {
                                         visible: true
                                     }
                                 },
                                 series: [{
                                     data: [
                                         { arg: 0, val: 1 },
                                         { arg: 2, val: 4 },
                                         { arg: 4, val: 2 }]
                                 }, {
                                     data: [
                                         { arg: 1, val: 1 },
                                         { arg: 2.5, val: 9 },
                                         { arg: 3.7, val: 5.6 }]
                                 }]
                             });

var panelChart = new Ext.Panel({
 items: [{
  contentEl: 'chartContainer',
  border: false,
  layout: 'fit'
 }]
});

<body>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
```

If I remove the div from the body the chart doesn't appear in the panel :(

But like this it does not change the chart size with the window size. I don't want to declare the div in the body.

Any ideas? I would to use it like Highcharts for Extjs. It's possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `html` property of the panel to render your div in the panel's body. Create your chart in the `afterrender` event of the panel, so that the div is available. Finally, use the `resize` event to resize your div when the panel is resized.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16872494/1387519). The charting lib is different but the principles are exactly the same.

**Edit**

I can't get to make the chart resize in height. Since I know nothing about the lib, I just refered to this [support question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q497183)... But I think it is the normal behaviour for the type of chart you're using.

Anyway, here's my code (also, in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/QPYyM/)):

```
Ext.define('DxChartPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel'

    ,resizable: true

    ,html: '<div class="chartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>'

    ,initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.on({
            scope: this
            ,resize: function(panel) {
                var ct = panel.body.down('.chartContainer'),
                    chart = $(ct.dom).dxChart('instance');

                ct.setSize(panel.body.getSize());

                chart._render({ animate: false })
                // Animated resize
                //chart._render();
            }
            ,afterrender: function(panel) {
                var el = this.body,
                    target = el.down('.chartContainer');
                target.setSize(el.getSize());
                this.createChart($(target.dom));
            }
        });
    }

    ,createChart: function(target) {
        var c = target.dxChart({
            size:{height:200,height:300},
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                label: {
                    visible: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: [
                    { arg: 0, val: 1 },
                    { arg: 2, val: 4 },
                    { arg: 4, val: 2 }]
            }, {
                data: [
                    { arg: 1, val: 1 },
                    { arg: 2.5, val: 9 },
                    { arg: 3.7, val: 5.6 }]
            }]
        });
    }
});

Ext.create('DxChartPanel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,title: "Resizable Panel"
    ,height: 300
    ,width: 300
});

Ext.widget('window', {
    autoShow: true
    ,title: "dxChart Window"
    ,width: 350
    ,height: 350
    ,layout: 'fit'
    ,items: [Ext.create('DxChartPanel', {
        border: false
    })]
});
```

Comment: Thanks rixo, the resize doesnt work :/ the chart only responds if i change the size of browser...

Comment: Devexpress isn't open source, so I can't test myself. If you update your question with your code, maybe I'll be able to spot what's wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I could achieve. To do better, you'll have to use your knowledge of dxChart ;)

Comment: Hi rixo, I've used my knowledge of ChartJS and your sample :) You have almost done everything but couple of little details

Answer (score 1):

There were only two things with rixo's code which prevented resize to work properly:

Firstly, size of chart was set as constant (instead of being calculated based on container's size)

I've removed line

```
size:{height:200,height:300}
```

*UPDATE*: there was a single issue with size, there is no need in timeout

<strike>Secondly, by some reason ExtJS fires "resize" event *before* actual resize (so container still has exactly the same size)</strike>

To re-render chart after real resize, I've added setTimeout call with zero interval

```
            setTimeout(function () {                            
                chart._render({ animate: false })
            })
```

Now it appears to be working and resizing properly

Reworked version of rixo's fiddle is accessible here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kaatula/4sHkZ/1/

Code now looks like:

```
Ext.define('DxChartPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel'

    ,resizable: true

    ,html: '<div class="chartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>'

    ,initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.on({
            scope: this
            ,resize: function(panel) {

                var ct = panel.body.down('.chartContainer'),
                    chart = $(ct.dom).dxChart('instance');

                console.log($(ct.dom).height());
                ct.setSize(panel.body.getSize());

                setTimeout(function () {                            
                    chart._render({ animate: false })
                })
            }
            ,afterrender: function(panel) {
                var el = this.body,
                    target = el.down('.chartContainer');
                target.setSize(el.getSize());
                this.createChart($(target.dom));
            }
        });
    }

    ,createChart: function(target) {
        var c = target.dxChart({
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                label: {
                    visible: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: [
                    { arg: 0, val: 1 },
                    { arg: 2, val: 4 },
                    { arg: 4, val: 2 }]
            }, {
                data: [
                    { arg: 1, val: 1 },
                    { arg: 2.5, val: 9 },
                    { arg: 3.7, val: 5.6 }]
            }]
        });
    },
    resize: function () {
        console.log(resize);
    }
});

Ext.create('DxChartPanel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,title: "Resizable Panel"
    ,height: 300
    ,width: 300
});

Ext.widget('window', {
    autoShow: true
    ,title: "dxChart Window"
    ,width: 350
    ,height: 350
    ,layout: 'fit'
    ,items: [Ext.create('DxChartPanel', {
        border: false
    })]
});
```

Comment: Well done. The funny thing is that I tried to remove that size line, and the chart didn't render. Maybe I missed a syntax error, or didn't wait long enough for the fiddle to load... The other funny thing is that your code works perfectly for me, even without the `setTimeout` (in FF and Chrome, Linux).

Comment: rixo, it was my bad; there is really no need in setTimeout. 

I tested height of container before the call of ct.setSize