# ExtJS How to override onRender so that I can get correct component?

Tags: extjs, render, onrender

I'm trying to get the size of a div that rendered as a component.

```
Ext.define('EDS.view.selector.Container', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.selectorcontainer',

    layout: 'fit',

    initComponent: function(){

        this.items = [
                {
                    xtype: 'tabpanel',
                    defaults: {
                        bodyPadding: 10
                    },
                    layout: 'fit',
                    items:[
                         {
                             title: 'Organization',
                             id: 'selector-organization',
                             tag: 'div',                             
                             html: 'div here',
                             height: '100%',

                            onRender: function(){

                                //// Render D3
                                // Selector
                                console.log("onRender");
                                console.log(this.height);
                                console.log(this.width);

                                var divId = Ext.getCmp('selector-organization').id + "-body";
                                var divHeight = Ext.get(divId).getHeight();
                                var divWidth = Ext.get(divId).getWidth();
                                console.log(divHeight);
                                console.log(divWidth);
                                renderSelectorOrgView(divId, divHeight, divWidth);   

                                this.callParent();
                             },
......
......
```

And this onRender function interrupts the normal render process. The whole layout got corrupted and the div (#selector-organization-body) is very small. So I'm wondering if I was overriding the onRender in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, that's broken. The problem is that `callParent` and such methods are only available for methods that have been passed through `Ext.define`.

You can emulate `callParent` yourself by calling the parent method with the current scope and arguments. In your case, replace `this.callParent()` (which is missing the arguments, by the way) with this line:

```
Ext.panel.Panel.prototype.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: That's too tough. I think there must be an elegant way to invoke js functions after a component get rendered.

Comment: You're right, but that's not the question you've asked here. Overriding is not the best solution here, you should use a listener on the `afterrender` event. See the links I've posted in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18331713/1387519) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the onRender function on all Panels do this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.tab.Panel, {
    onRender: function() {
        this.callParent();

        console.log('do something');
    }
});
```